# Instantiate Apigee.Client With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, apigee

I just learned about Apigee yesterday and decided to tinker with it a bit. I am working through the installation article to implement it into JavaScript and am supposed to, "...pass a JSON object with the UUID or name for your App Services organization and application when [I] instantiate it." I guess I am not adequately acquainted with JSON enough to understand exactly what the instruction is wanting me to do. Could someone please explain to me in more detail what I am supposed to be doing at this point.

This is the code they supplied me with...

```
var client_creds = {
    orgName:'your-org',
    appName:'your-app'
}

//Initializes the SDK. Also instantiates Apigee.MonitoringClient
var dataClient = new Apigee.Client(client_creds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the text (`'your-org'` and `'your-app'`) properties in the client_creds object with your org and app name (found at https://apigee.com/usergrid/#!/org-overview).

You've now created an instance of the `Apigee.Client` class; when you use the SDK to make API calls, it'll know which {org} and {app} to place the calls to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have already signed up with apigee as a developer. If that is not the case click here to [signup](https://developers.apigee.com/get-started)

Once you signup, By default something called as organisation is created for you. By default the org name is your username. Also By default an app called 'sandbox' is created for you within apigee. To see them go here: https://apigee.com/usergrid/#!/org-overview.

Now you can use these things in your sdk, Replace 'Your-org' with your org name and 'Your-app' with 'sandbox' (because by default this is already created or you can create one and that here)

ex:

```
var client_creds = {
    orgName:'naveen',                # where 'naveen' is a example username/orgname
    appName:'sandbox'
}
```